# Deploying a Ruby on Rails project with React components to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, heroku, thin

I'm trying to deploy a Ruby on Rails application, with a [Node.js](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) front end to [Heroku](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroku). I'm getting:

[image]

Here's my Procfile:

```
web:bundle exec thin start -p $PORT
```

Here's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "collectize",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "[Heroku link][heroku]",
  "main": "index.js",
  "directories": {
    "doc": "docs",
    "test": "test"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "4.1.1",
    "npm": "2.1.x"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "postinstall": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack"
    "start": "node ./app/assets/javascripts/bundle.js"

  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/winterblack/Collectize.git"
    "start": "web:bundle exec thin start -p $PORT"

  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/winterblack/Collectize/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/winterblack/Collectize#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.10.4",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
    "flux": "^2.1.1",
    "react": "^15.2.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.2.1",
    "react-router": "^2.5.2",
    "webpack": "^1.13.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

Here's my Heroku log:

```
2016-07-13T05:29:29.266840+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v28 created by wylliamjudd@gmail.com
2016-07-13T05:29:29.266840+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 7d61777 by wylliamjudd@gmail.com
2016-07-13T05:29:29.456774+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-07-13T05:29:29.517376+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2016-07-13T05:29:29.518479+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2016-07-13T05:29:32.421302+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2016-07-13T05:29:33.846617+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2016-07-13T05:29:41.586027+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2016-07-13T05:29:43.343250+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-07-13T05:29:43.343268+00:00 app[web.1]: > collectize@1.0.0 start /app
2016-07-13T05:29:43.343269+00:00 app[web.1]: > node ./app/assets/javascripts/bundle.js
2016-07-13T05:29:43.343269+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-07-13T05:29:43.513547+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-07-13T05:29:43.520060+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/app/assets/javascripts/bundle.js:88:4)
2016-07-13T05:29:43.520063+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/app/assets/javascripts/bundle.js:43:10)
2016-07-13T05:29:43.520063+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
2016-07-13T05:29:43.532480+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the collectize package,
2016-07-13T05:29:43.535942+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-07-13T05:29:44.242442+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-07-13T05:29:44.280956+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-07-13T05:29:44.282455+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-07-13T05:29:57.352852+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2016-07-13T05:29:59.471893+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-07-13T05:29:59.471938+00:00 app[web.1]: > collectize@1.0.0 start /app
2016-07-13T05:29:59.471940+00:00 app[web.1]: > node ./app/assets/javascripts/bundle.js
2016-07-13T05:29:59.471943+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-07-13T05:29:59.650297+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-07-13T05:29:59.654711+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app/assets/javascripts/bundle.js:88
2016-07-13T05:29:59.655117+00:00 app[web.1]:     $(document).ready(function () {
2016-07-13T05:29:59.659133+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/app/assets/javascripts/bundle.js:88:4)
2016-07-13T05:29:59.659135+00:00 app[web.1]:     at __webpack_require__ (/app/app/assets/javascripts/bundle.js:20:30)
2016-07-13T05:29:59.659138+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
2016-07-13T05:29:59.659139+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
2016-07-13T05:29:59.659140+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
2016-07-13T05:29:59.659141+00:00 app[web.1]:     at startup (node.js:119:16)
2016-07-13T05:29:59.672227+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v0.10.30
2016-07-13T05:29:59.672464+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v2.1.18
2016-07-13T05:29:59.672884+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2016-07-13T05:29:59.673045+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! collectize@1.0.0 start: `node ./app/assets/javascripts/bundle.js`
2016-07-13T05:29:59.673873+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the collectize package,
2016-07-13T05:29:59.674006+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2016-07-13T05:29:59.674125+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2016-07-13T05:29:59.674412+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get their info via:
2016-07-13T05:29:59.674578+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls collectize
2016-07-13T05:29:59.674919+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2016-07-13T05:29:59.677307+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-07-13T05:30:00.517992+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-07-13T05:30:00.501781+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-07-13T05:30:01.842475+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=collectize.herokuapp.com request_id=111967a3-b265-4447-8e7e-da8a723b5b48 fwd="24.176.249.167" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

On my local machine I need to run:

```
~$ bundle install
~$ npm install
~$ webpack
~$ thin start
```

Do I have to have Heroku run `node bundle.js` in order to get my [React](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_%28JavaScript_library%29) components? If so, why don't I have to do that on my machine? The difference between what happens on Heroku, and what happens on my local machine is the primary thing I need clarification on.

This line in the log seems important:

```
/app/app/assets/javascripts/bundle.js:88
$(document).ready(function () {
```

I've almost never run a JavaScript file with Node.js (aside from some debugging); I almost always work with JavaScript in a web application in HTML. I tried running `node bundle.js` locally, and got `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`. I tried changing it to `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",` ...but then I just got the same error for document is not defined.

I honestly have no idea where to go from here. I don't understand why Heroku needs to run node bundle.js, or whether it even does.

I did try deleting the Procfile and just putting `"bundle exec thin start -p $PORT"` as my start script in my package.json, and that actually got my website "up", but with no React components (and so completely blank).

Comment: What do you mean nodejs front-end? Heroku allows one server listening per app, so you would need 2 apps, one for rails, one for node.

Comment: I mean that my project uses react. I thought that javascript runs in the front end by the browser. Clearly, I don't understand this well.

Comment: I see. I suspect the issue is Heroku is detecting the wrong buildpack. Can you run `heroku buildpacks` and tell me the output?

Comment: heroku/ruby and heroku/nodejs. I installed both of these myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently all I had to do was delete my nodejs buildpack and readd it with index 1. My website immediately started working when I did that. Then I deleted the start script from my package.json, and the website still worked.Then I deleted my procfile and the website still works.

So, the only issue was the order of the buildpacks, no procfile required, no start script required.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that with Heroku, you need to include a favicon. The app will crash otherwise.

Include this in your `<head>`:

```
<link href="/images/favicon.png" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png"/>
```

Adjust the path, filename, and type accordingly.

Comment: Added the favicon but it didn't fix my problem. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is Heroku is setup to serve either a Rails backend or a Node.js isomorphic frontend. You can't do both in the same app.

1. Use two apps. `myapp-api.herokuapp.com` is Rails and `myapp-web.herokuapp.com` is React isomorphic. I personally host the React frontend on `netlify.com` which is a static hosting service.
2. Build using webpack during the build and serve static files from Rails. [webpack-rails](https://github.com/mipearson/webpack-rails) looks promising.

Remove the nodejs buildpack, and decide how you want to serve your frontend. Separate app, or static build.

Comment: I'm sure this is not true. I was dropped from appAcademy, but still have access to their curriculum. I can see dozens of Rails/React projects deployed to Heroku in a single app. So, I'm sure this isn't the fix, but unfortunately I can't get help from the TAs anymore, so I'm not sure exactly what the problem is. But I know it's not this.

Comment: It just started working. I removed the nodejs buildpack from heroku and readded it with index 1, and apparently that solved the problem.